# agile web development 4 with rails 4 orders form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After checkout we have a form to fill with data from the user, if not fill we are presented with errors, after fill the data if we click Place Order it is suppose that will be an update of database, but all data disappears from the form and display errors like the first time with no data.

Here is my code:

/app/views/carts/_cart.html.erb:

```
<h2>Your Cart</h2>
<table>
  <%= render(cart.line_items) %>

  <tr class="total_line">
    <td colspan="2">Total</td>
    <td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
<%= button_to "Checkout", new_order_path, method: :get %>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
<%= button_to 'Empty cart', cart, method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

/app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    if @cart.line_items.empty?
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Your cart is empty"
      return
    end

    @order = Order.new
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil

        format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: 
          'Thank you for your order.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created,
          location: @order }

      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors,
          status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:name, :address, :email, :pay_type)
    end
  #...
end
```

/app/views/orders/new.html.erb:

```
<div class="depot_form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please Enter Your Details</legend>
    <%= render 'form' %>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

/app/views/orders/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %>
      prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
    <%= f.text_field :name, size: 40 %>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br>
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
    <%= f.text_area :address, rows: 3, cols: 40 %>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
    <%= f.email_field :email, size: 40 %>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :pay_type %><br>
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
    <%= f.select :pay_type, Order::PAYMENT_TYPES,
                  prompt: 'Select a payment method' %>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
    <%= f.submit 'Place Order' %>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  </div>
<% end %>
```

/app/models/order.rb:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  PAYMENT_TYPES = [ "Check", "Credit card", "Purchase order" ]
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  # ...
  validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true
  validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES
end
```

/app/models/line_item.rb:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
  def total_price
    product.price * quantity
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok , it is solved, the problem is in app/models/order.rb 
What I have when the update orders do not work
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  PAYMENT_TYPES = [ "Check", "Credit card", "Purchase order" ]

validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true
  validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES
  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
    cart.line_items.each do |item|
      item.cart_id = nil
      line_items << item
    end
  end
end

After change with  attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :product, :name, :address, :email, :pay_type

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :product, :name, :address, :email, :pay_type
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  PAYMENT_TYPES = [ "Check", "Credit card", "Purchase order" ]

validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true
  validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES
  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
    cart.line_items.each do |item|
      item.cart_id = nil
      line_items << item
    end
  end
end

Now, everything is working has expected.

Thanks

Regards